# Find path through binary tree to get to desired node #

Tags: binary, binary-operations

Say we have a binary tree. If know how many nodes X there are in the tree, how can we navigate from the root node to the node with value X without any backtracking? I am doing binary arithmetic and seeing some patterns but can't make the breakthrough.

Here is a sample tree:

```
                  1
               /      \
             2           3
           /   \        /   \
          4     5      6     7
         / \    / \   /  \    /\
        8   9  10 11 12 13   14 15
```

It seems to be better to start with 1 instead of 0 for root node, but not sure if it matters much really. My guess to start at the root node and take the left path Y times, and then if necessary go to right node from there, and then you have a new tree, with the same problem but smaller tree.

So if X = 16, we take the left path 4 times, followed by 0 right path.
but if X = 11, we take a left path 1 times, and right path twice.

I know there is a pattern here but can't figure it out lol.

*Actual goal:*
My actual goal is to find the next node on the tree to add a child to, given the number of current nodes on the tree. This is part of heap implementation. In the tree above, the node to add to is #8, for a balanced binary tree.

Comment: For $16$ you have to take left path $4$ times

Comment: A *VERY* well studied problem.  Look up the A* algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the number of the node in binary. Ignore the first bit, which is always $1$. Read the remainder from left to right: a $0$ means *go left*, and a $1$ means *go right*. For instance, $10$ is $1010_2$, so it is reached by branching $010=LRL$. Its left child is $LRLL$, corresponding to $0100$ and hence to the number $10100_2=20$; its right child is $LRLR$, corresponding to $0101$ and hence to the number $10101_2=21$.

To find the parent of node $n$, write $n$ in binary, remove the last bit, and write the result in decimal. Equivalently, the parent node’s number is $\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor$, since dropping the last bit is dividing by $2$ and ignoring any remainder.

Comment: interesting wonder why this works out, as usual visualizing for me is understanding

Comment: so for a heap algo, if the # of nodes is X, for an insert you want to add a new node at X+1, so that's easy to find. but the problem is how do you find out the parent of X+1, that's where I am stuck rn.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: It works because the numbering scheme ensures that the number of the left child is always twice the number of the parent, and the number of the right child is one more than that. In binary multiplying by $2$ is just appending a $0$, and multiplying by $2$ and adding $1$ is just appending a $1$.

Comment: thanks, any idea how to find the parent node Y of node X? How to find Y? :) feeling dumb over here.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: I’ve just added that.

Comment: Your heap problem is quite simple. If there are $X$ nodes then insert $X+1$ at parent node $\lfloor (X+1)/2\rfloor$. If $X+1$ is even, it goes as the left child. Otherwise right child.

Answer (score 3):

At node labelled $v$, the left child is having label $2v$ and the right child is having label $2v+1$. So the parent node of a node labelled $x$ is labelled $\lfloor x/2\rfloor$.

This allows us to figure out the reverse path easily. From $16\to\lfloor16/2\rfloor=8\to\lfloor8/2\rfloor=4\to\lfloor4/2\rfloor=2\to\lfloor2/2\rfloor=1$. So the path you have to follow is: $1,2,4,8,16$.

Now it becomes easy to figure out whether you have to go left or right. If the next node in the path is having odd label, we are to take the right child. If it is having an even label, take the left child. You can do this process simultaneously with the process of finding the parent node.

Comment: this is a good explanation thanks

Comment: makes me wonder how floor operations work in computation, no idea

Comment: @Alexander Just find $x/2$ and truncate the portion after decimal point. If you store $x$ as an integer, some languages calculate $x/2$ as an integer and automatically truncate the decimal part. Other languages may calculate it as a floating point in which case you can take help of the inbuilt floor functions or change the data type of $x/2$ to integer (if such an operation is supported).

Comment: As a naïve observer, this requires 2(log(n))  instead of log(n) to find the node.  I am wondering if there is a way to do it in log(n)? Brian's answer to convert to binary does that? or what am I missing?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Converting decimal to binary has complexity $O(\log n)$, then reading the binary and deciding left or right has complexity $O(\log n)$.

Comment: what i mean is first you figure out the reverse path with is O(log n) and then you traverse that backwards which is O(log n) so hence my calc of O(2logn). So I guess fundamentally this answer is different from Brian's

Comment: @AlexanderMills In my previous comment I explained how even Brian's answer consists of two steps each of $O(\log n)$ complexity: converting the decimal label of a node to binary and then reading the binary.